# How to implement social api (facebook) for monodroid/mvvmcross application?

Tags: facebook, api, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Which api do you use to implement facebook in monodroid/mvvmcross application ?
Someone tried to do a java bindings library from facebook android sdk ?
I just have to send a picture on the wall of a facebook account (graph api).

Answer (score 0):

I used the C# Facebook SDK - http://csharpsdk.org/ , it's got a version for Phone and RT. What I ended doing was writing an interface for Facebook functions, and then 2 implementations, that takes the platform specific Facebook client as a constructor parameter. That way my core PCL code could talk to the generic interface, and I set the specific version in the platform Setup

Don't know about Android though